# Junit Mock external static Interfaces

Tags: junit

We are using external package which provides interface to get service instances on which we make web service calls.

API is like ClientServiceInterface.getService(location);

Where getService is static method. I want to mock this , how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a mocking framework that'll be able to do byte-code manipulation as static methods aren't mockable without resorting to that.

Take a look at [Powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) and in particular the section on [Mocking Static Methods](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic).

Comment: Can i use it along with junit or should i need create separate test suites , one using junit and other using powermock